# How to retrieve json data in real time in Unity3d using sockets?

Tags: sockets, unity-game-engine

I am using a python program to send a json file which sends:

```
{point1_number(int),x1(float),y1(float)
point2_number(int),x2(float),y2(float)}
```

using sockets. (ps: The json file is updated and sent continuously in real time)

I want to retrieve these co-ordinates in unity. How can I do so?

Comment: Most of the time I see people use the [WWW class to do things like that](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)

Comment: Ive tried the WWW  class. 
I'm looking for a more specific answer,that uses System.sockets ;